# Fedora 17 not saving iptables

Tags: iptables, fedora

For some reason my Fedora is not saving changes made to my iptables.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
service iptables status
service iptables restart

Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  status iptables.service
```

Then when starting, my changes are not there anymore.

Also tried saving:

```
[root@VTM01 ~]# service iptables save
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  save iptables.service
Unknown operation save
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under previous versions of Fedora, it required `service iptables save`.

Looks like it has been changed to `/usr/libexec/iptables.init save`.

[3.8.3. Saving IPTables Rules](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/17/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables-Saving_IPTables_Rules.html)

Comment: Check out the post, I tried this earlier but did not include it because I thought I was imagining the command.

Comment: You're right!  Looks like they changed it under Fedora 17.  I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

It have change once again.

```
sudo service iptables save
```

does not works anymore
you have to edit the config file to does that.

```
sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP="yes"
IPTABLES_SAVE_ON_RESTART="yes"
```